# How to create a switch button for 3 cases in html

Tags: html

I would like to ask that is it possible in html that I can create a switch button for 3 cases. When I switch to the left, condition 1 is true. When I switch to the right, condition 2 is true. At the middle point, two conditions are true. I want to have this kind of switch to be sure that at least always having one condition is true.

Are there anyone have an idea ? Thank you so much!

Comment: With pure HTML/CSS, my idea would be to create a radio button group with three input elements. Then style it in a way that it looks like the switch you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', BtnCtrl);
function BtnCtrl() {
  var self = this;
  var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  
  //Just Set Defaults
  var conditionA = true;
  var conditionB = true;
  
  self.syncDOM = function() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'ConditionA: ' + conditionA + '; ConditionB:' + conditionB;
  };
  
  self.onBtnClick = function(event) {
    var condition = ((this.dataset || {}).condition || '').toLowerCase();
    
    switch(condition) {
      case 'a':
        conditionA = true;
        conditionB = false;
        break;
        
      case 'b':
        conditionB = true;
        conditionA = false;
        break;
        
      default:
        conditionA = true;
        conditionB = true;
    }
    
    console.log('isValid ConditionA', conditionA);
    console.log('isValid ConditionB', conditionB);
    self.syncDOM();
  };

  self.syncDOM();
  for(var i = 0, btn; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btn = btns[i];
    btn.addEventListener('click', self.onBtnClick.bind(btn));
  }
}
```

```css
#result { background: lightcoral; padding: 1em; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<button class="btn" id="btnLeft" data-condition="a">LEFT</button>
<button class="btn" id="btnMiddle">MIDDLE</button>
<button class="btn" id="btnRight"  data-condition="b">RIGHT</button>

<div id=result></div>
```